# How do you animate Speed Control in Video editing (and slow down a clip gradually)? - Blender 2.8

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

So I'm having significant problems animating a video clips speed control.

I've watched tutorials and searched for answers, but they don't address my issues.

After:
- select clip, and adding effect strip speed control
- then selecting the speed effect and unchecking "Stretch to input..."

My clip is frozen on a single frame, and no longer scrubs through the frames.

I've tried i add key frame animating the speed factor (I can't add keyframes this way - it just does nothing when speed effect is selected then press i), 
and un-checking "use as speed" same result.

Also the key frames are not added to the key editor in the Graph Editor, and in the key menu, all the add key and easing menu items are grayed out.

What are the correct steps to animate/control that animation of speed in the Blender 2.8 video editor?

[image: No Keyframes in Graph]

[image: No change in frame image]

And checking "Use as speed" has the same effect - none - no gradual slow down in playback - just the same frame.

Comment: I found part of the problem - I did figure out how to get the key frames to show up (I had the show errors button selected above the graph editor and that was hiding the key frames).

I think my frame rate may have something to do with my troubles - I've had mixed results.

I found theses:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTA7KI2xB-c

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105621/blender-vse-can-i-make-movie-strip-gradually-slow-down-or-gradually-speed-up